# Understanding the proof: $x^TAx = 0$ $\implies$ A is also skew-symmetric

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, symmetric-matrices

While reviewing this answer to [the question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1623934/prove-xtax-0-implies-a-is-skew-symmetric) which was asked before, I caught an error in my mind based on what I learnt so far. Here is the answer:

> It is true. We have: $$(x+y)^TA(x+y) = 0 \implies x^TAx + y^TAx + x^TAy + y^TAy = 0.$$But $x^TAx = y^TAy = 0$, so we have: $$x^TAy = -y^TAx.$$Take $x = e_i$ and $y = e_j$ to get $a_{ij} = -a_{ji}$.

My concern is about this part:

> Take $x = e_i$ and $y = e_j$ to get $a_{ij} = -a_{ji}$

My question is, isn't this a particular example? I mean we said $x^TAx=0$ and it is true **for all** $x$, so in one **sub-solution** (which is $x=e_i$ and $y=e_j$), we said $a_{ij} = -a_{ji}$ how about if for other $x$ and $y$ vectors this not happen? I mean if there is a $x$ and $y$ for example which results in $a_{ij} = 2a_{ji}$?

Comment: The *hypothesis* is that $x^TAx=0$ is true *for all* $x$, i.e. you are *assuming* that this statement is true. So in particular it must be true for any specific choice of $x$.

Comment: @Dave Thank you for your explanation, but I am still not convinced. yeah $x^tAx = 0$ for all x , but who knows if there is a vector which satisfy $x^tAx=0$ and then results in $a_{ij} = 5a_{ji}$ ? It is not enough, I think you understand why. This is not natural .

Comment: if such a vector $x$ existed to produce a relation like that, then the matrix would be trivial, which is certainly not true (in general). So such an $x$ cannot exist.

Comment: @Dave Oh cool, explain more! What about for other relations except $a_{ij} = -a_{ji} $?I think this an interesting explanation

Comment: We already obtained the relation $a_{i,j}=-a_{j,i}$, so if we had another relation of the form $a_{i,j}=ca_{j,i}$ for some $c\neq -1$, then combining the two relations would imply $-a_{j,i}=ca_{j,i}$, which tells us that $a_{j,i}=0$ for all $i,j$, i.e. $A=0$.

Comment: @Dave No one explained like this before to me! Thanks! So lets go further, how about the case when the result is: $a_{ij}= a_{ji}^2 +a_{ji}$ ?

Comment: In principle, you can obtain weird relations like this (probably not that exact one). I would try picking different values of $x$ and $y$ and see what kinds of relations you get.

Comment: @Dave So you mean maybe I'm right?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. There is certainly no flaw in the proof of the titular claim. However, you can also plug in all kinds of values for $x$ and $y$ to that last step to obtain weird equations. I would suggest trying it for some $x$ and $y$ and see what you get.

Comment: @Dave I know what you're saying, but if I accept this proof, I memorized it and not learned. That why I want to know the reason , a convincing one .

Comment: The argument typically is if you are not in characteristic two then $A = -A^T \implies x^TA x = x^T A^T x = x^T(-A) x = -x^TA x =0$ for all $x$ (total isotropy) since the transpose of a scalar (or $1\times 1$ matrix) is that scalar.  What you are looking at is the other direction and have derived $x^TAy = -y^TAx= \big(-y^TAx\big)^T = -x^T A^T y=x^T (-A^T) y$ which holds for arbitrary $x,y$ so $A=-A^T$ [with some care this direction is meaningful over characteristic two]

Comment: @user8675309 Cool! But at the end part, how do we know that $x^t$ has left inverse and also $y$ has right inverse?

Comment: There is no notion of left or right inverse involved.  As I said it holds for arbitrary $x,y$ -- your solution then says consider each possible std basis vector pairing as for $x$ and a $y$ to confirm the result for each component of $A$. You are going to need to spend some time carefully working through what has actually been said here.

Comment: @user8675309 I will provide complete proof myself soon, I realized the thing .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given $ x^t A x = 0 $ for **all** vectors x, let's consider the vectors $x$ and $ y $:

$$ (x + y)^t A (x + y) = x^t A x + x^t A y + y^t A x + y^t A y $$

Given our initial condition, $( x^t A x = 0 $) and $( y^t A y = 0 $), the equation becomes:

$$ x^t A y + y^t A x = 0 $$

Since this is true for all vectors $x$ and $y$, we have:

$$ x^t A y = -y^t A x $$Since $y^tAx$ is scalar , it is equal to its transpose i.e $x^tAy$ , so this implies $$  x^t A y = x^t (-A^t) y $$
implies$$  x^t (A + A^t) y = 0 $$

For the expression $ x^t (A + A^t) y $ to be zero for all $x $ and $y$, we claim that the matrix $( A + A^t $) must be the zero matrix i.e
$$\forall x,y~~;x^t (A + A^t) y=0 \Rightarrow A+A^t=0$$
I will prove this by contradiction, i.e. $$if~ A+A^t\neq0 \Rightarrow \exists x,y~~ ;~~x^t (A + A^t) y \neq 0 $$
when $A+A^t \neq 0$ this means there exists at least one non zero element in it . For that we can choose $x$ as $e_i$ and $y$ as $e_j$ such that $(i,j)$ = coordinates of that non zero element and so $e_i^t(A+A^t)e_j = (A+A^t)_{ij}\neq 0$
So
$$ A + A^t = 0 $$
$$A=-A^t$$

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite $x^TAy = -y^TAx$ in a more extended form as
$$
\sum_{i,j}x_iy_j(a_{i,j} + a_{j,i}) = 0 \tag{1}
$$
which *must* be true for all possible $x$ and $y$.

What we are trying to do here is to solve this in terms of relations between matrix coefficients $a_{i,j}$.

Author in the answer you're citing suggests to choose such $x$ and $y$ that all the elements in sum $(1)$ but one $x_iy_j(a_{i,j} + a_{j,i}) = a_{i,j} + a_{j,i}$ eliminate, which leads to solution:
$$a_{i,j} = -a_{j,i} \quad \forall\;i, j. \tag{2}$$

---

What we need here now is to answer [two questions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necessity_and_sufficiency): is this solution 1) sufficient and 2) necessary. If so, this would mean that $(1)$ is simply equivalent to $(2)$.

It's pretty easy to see that this system is *sufficient* to solve $(1)$ for all $x$, $y$ (you just have all the summands to be zero in left hand side of equation). This means that no more relations to $a_{i,j}$ than we have in $(2)$ needed.

*Necessity* means that none of relations from $(2)$ can be removed. Consider any other system with some pair of indices $i,j$ for which $a_{i,j} + a_{j,i} \neq 0$. For it we can take again $x = e_i$, $y = e_j$ and get straightforward contradiction to $(1)$:
$$
\sum_{i,j}x_iy_j(a_{i,j} + a_{j,i}) = a_{i,j} + a_{j,i} \neq 0.
$$
Thus, $(2)$ is necessary for $(1)$.

This is pretty much it, we can now claim that $(1)$ is *equivalent* to $(2)$ and so this is only possible solution – anything else must be equivalent to it.